# Ten Tricky Mathematicians

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, liars

Somewhere on the Hyperbolic Plane, you encounter ten mathematicians. You know that some of them always tell the truth while the rest always lie. Each of them knows which of the others tell the truth and which do not.

Let $g$ be the number of mathematicians that tell the truth. Let $h$ be the *sum of the indices* of the mathematicians that tell the truth (e.g. if mathematicians 4 and 5 tell the truth, $h=4+5=9$).

You ask the mathematicians for the values of $g$ and $h$ and receive the following answers:

**Mathematician   1:** $\quad g = 6 \quad \lor \quad h = 12$

**Mathematician   2:** $\quad g = 3 \quad \lor \quad h = 12$

**Mathematician   3:** $\quad g = 4 \quad \lor \quad h = 11$

**Mathematician   4:** $\quad g = 4 \quad \lor \quad h = 25$

**Mathematician   5:** $\quad g = 2 \quad \lor \quad h = 17$

**Mathematician   6:** $\quad g = 3 \quad \lor \quad h = 24$

**Mathematician   7:** $\quad g = 5 \quad \lor \quad h = 23$

**Mathematician   8:** $\quad g = 5 \quad \lor \quad h = 11$

**Mathematician   9:** $\quad g = 6 \quad \lor \quad h = 23$

**Mathematician 10:** $\quad g = 5 \quad \lor \quad h = 16$

> **Q:** Which of the mathematicians are telling the truth?

---

***Note 1:*** $\lor$ is the boolean "or" operator, so only **one** of the statements needs to be correct in order for a mathematician to be telling the truth.

***Note 2:*** I constructed this puzzle using a search program that enumerates all possibilities to ensure correctness. It would therefore be nice to get solutions that do not *rely on computer programs themselves.*

Comment: By note 1, can i say that the lying mathematician also have just one lie out of both?

Comment: @manshu: No. $a \lor b$ is true iff at least one of $a,b$ is true. If just one of $a,b$ is a lie, $a \lor b$ is still true.

Comment: I really like the concept but it is a little too easy.  I would love to see a much more complicated one someday.

Comment: I don't understand this at all - the mathematicians either *always lie* or *always tell the truth*, and yet you have constructed this so that a mathematician can not only do both, but be considered to be truthful in so doing?

Comment: @question_asker  If one of these mathematicians said "Either I tell the truth or I always lie" you'd *know* they're a truth teller.

Comment: @PaulEvans That's sort of immaterial to what I'm saying.

Comment: @question_asker: It is not immaterial. "The sky is blue or green" is a true statement, and someone who always tells the truth could easily say it.

Comment: @kundor I get what's being said from an Obnoxious Nerd perspective, but at that point it's silly to bother with the "truth tellers/liars" conceit. This puzzle could easily have been written in a way that doesn't rely on something so cognitively dissonant.

Comment: The ones I know sure do (this is, I think, where I do one of those punctuation things that looks like somebody sticking their tongue out at you)

Comment: @question_asker  You calling mathematical logic something from the "Obnoxious Nerd perspective" may or may not (a tautologically *true* statement!!) give you street cred, but mathematicians ain't gonna buy it.  BTW I'd *love* to play some gambling games with you. :) )

Comment: @paulevans now you've gone and messed up the order. If you're trying to imply I'm bad at gambling, though...

Comment: @question_asker  My apologies, didn't know you'd respond so quickly.  Perhaps we should take this to chat.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

By case distinction on the value $g$:

- If $g=1$, then the unique truth teller Mx must claim that $h=x$; contradiction.
- If $g=2$, then M5 tells the truth ($g=2$). The other truth teller Mx must claim that $h=x+5$; contradiction.
- If $g=3$, then M2 and M6 tell the truth ($g=3$). The other truth teller Mx must claim that $h=x+2+6=x+8$; contradiction.
- If $g=4$, then M3 and M4 tell the truth ($g=4$). The other two truth tellers Mx and My must claim that $h=x+y+7$; in particular, they both must claim the same value of $h$. The pairs (M1 and M2) and (M3 and M8) do not work.
  Only (M7 and M9) works.
- If $g=5$, then M7, M8, M10 tell the truth. The other two truth tellers Mx and My must claim that $h=x+y+25$; this value $h$ is too large.
- If $g\ge6$, then at least four guys must state the correct value of $h$; contradiction.

To summarize:

> M3, M4, M7 and M9 tell the truth with $g=4$ and $h=23$.

Furthermore, there is a second solution:

> None of them tells the truth with $g=0$ and $h=0$. (For this, you must accept that the empty sum takes value $0$.)

Comment: Second solution is fascinating.

Comment: @AycanYaşıt Second solution is invalid, the author already specified that **some of them** always tell the truth.

Comment: @Ninety-Three The answer is only valid if **none of them** tell the truth, not all of them.

Comment: Just as a note: When doing this, I found it to be simpler to reduce everything using the obvious information. E.g. If 8 is correct then there is $g*=6-1=5$ other people telling the truth or the sum of the rest is $h*=11-8=3$ (Basically this directly eliminates $x$ from your reasoning)

Answer (score 6):

By iterating through the possible values of `g`, then filling the remaining missing mathematicians who use the correct value `h`, I was able to determine another solution:

> Mathematicians 2 and 6 claimed the value `g = 3`, and by iterating through the remaining mathematicians, Mathematician 3 claimed the value `h = 11`. 3 mathematicians, and sum of indices = 11.

**Edit**

Upon further consideration, my answer is actually invalid:

> If this solution is valid, then Mathematician 8 is also telling the truth (e.g. `h = 11`) which cannot be, so this is a contradiction and is not a valid solution.

Comment: Looks like I tricked 2 people

Answer (score 3):

The truth tellers are:

> M3, M4, M7 and M9

Because:

> Can't be 2 truth tellers because that would mean M5 and someone else.  All the others don't have their index plus 5 equal to their stated h, so no go.
>  Likewise there can't be g = 3 because we have M2 and M6. But there's no single other mathematician with h = index + 2 + 6, so no go.
>  Can't be g = 5 as 7 + 8 + 9 = 24. Minimum other two h's must be greater than be 27.  No h > 27, so no go.
>  Can't be g = 6 as then we'd have M1 and M9.  We'd then need 4 identical h's which isn't so, so no go.
>  This leaves g = 4 which gives us M3 and M4 with g = 4 and M7 and M9 with h = 3 + 4 + 7 + 9

<s>Sorry output's so ugly.  Can't get spoilers to newline properly.</s> Thank you @The Dark Truth

Just started looking at other answers and from @Gamow saw I missed g = 1 and g >= 7

Apologies to @Gamow for stealing M[0-9]+ notation.

Comment: I made the proper line breaks for your spoilers. Now you should work on correcting your spelling.

Comment: @TheDarkTruth Thanks, how'd you do it?

Comment: Secret :P (Put two spaces at the end of each line)

Comment: Ah! Thank you master, won't tell a soul ;)